# jQuery move second last element of array to first. How to achieve?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var unit_value = [1, 12, 100];
unit_value.push(unit_value.shift());
console.log(unit_value);
```

As you can see I moved the first element to last but I need to move second last element of the array to first How can I achieve this result? length of the array is dynamic.

Comment: what are you tying to achieve ? reverse ?

Comment: are you sure you want JQuery for this ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Index of value 100 is 1. But now I want to move it to first.

Comment: @Shubanker Fine in JS. If you can.

Answer (score 1):

**You can Try this:**

```
unit_value.unshift(unit_value.splice(unit_value.length-2,1)[0]);
```

`splice` removes element at 2nd last position and returns array of removed elements(in this case only one element).

`unshift` is used to insert the same element we removed at beginning of the array.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var unit_value = [1, 12, 13, 100, 15];
var seconLastEle = unit_value[unit_value.length-2];
unit_value.splice(unit_value.lastIndexOf(seconLastEle), 1);
unit_value.unshift(seconLastEle);
console.log(unit_value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery to achieve the solution, it's plain Javascript.

```
var unit_value = [1, 12, 100];
var removedUnit = unit_value.splice(unit_value.length - 2, 1)
unit_value.splice(0, 0, removedUnit)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are trying to move the 2nd last element of the array to the first place while making sure that the rest of the array remains the same.

Use [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
var unit_value = [1, 12, 100];

unit_value = [...unit_value.splice(unit_value.length - 2, 1), ...unit_value];
console.log(unit_value);
```

Comment: ... stand for what? BTW Working properly.

Comment: OK I read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax got it. Thanks for help.

Comment: @shahrushabh - Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function array_move(arr, old_index, new_index) {
  if (new_index >= arr.length) {
    var k = new_index - arr.length + 1;
    while (k--) {
      arr.push(undefined);
    }
  }
  arr.splice(new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
  return arr; // for testing
};
```

**demo**

```js
var unit_value = [1, 12, 100, 251];

function array_move(arr, old_index, new_index) {
  if (new_index >= arr.length) {
    var k = new_index - arr.length + 1;
    while (k--) {
      arr.push(undefined);
    }
  }
  arr.splice(new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
  return arr; // for testing
};

console.log(array_move(unit_value, (unit_value.length - 2), 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use `splice()` with negative index to pull second last from array  as array of one element and then `unshift()` first element back into original

```js
var unit_value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

unit_value.unshift(unit_value.splice(-2,1)[0])

console.log(unit_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

**One line solution**

unit_value.unshift(unit_value.splice(unit_value.length-2, 1)[0]);

Answer (score 0):

There may be a cleaner solution but here is one...

```js
var unit_value = [1, 12, 100];
unit_value = Array.prototype.concat(...[unit_value.splice(-2, 1),unit_value])
console.log(unit_value);
```